# add_action priority and taxonomy used in plugin

Tags: plugin-development, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, terms, register-taxonomy

I try to register my taxonomy in my plugin and use it after. So far I have done:

```
function custom_taxonomy() {
    $labels = array(
        ...
    );
    $args = array(
        ...
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'taxonomy', array( 'oferta' ), $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_taxonomy_miasta', 0 );
```

So as you can see I run it from `init` with priority `0`. After that I trying to call it from function and code, but it always gives me a `Invalid taxonomy` error.

Of course, there is no other error in code, cause when I try to get taxonomy values with `init` with priority lower than taxonomy, it works, but I need to recive value from my functions, `init` doesn't fit for me.

As far as I found there is a list in correct order how is it run:

```
muplugins_loaded
registered_taxonomy
registered_post_type
plugins_loaded <- here is my plugin loaded !!!!!!
sanitize_comment_cookies
setup_theme
load_textdomain
after_setup_theme
auth_cookie_malformed
auth_cookie_valid
set_current_user
init <- here I define taxonomy !!!!!!
widgets_init
register_sidebar
wp_register_sidebar_widget
wp_default_scripts
wp_default_stypes
admin_bar_init
add_admin_bar_menus
wp_loaded
parse_request
send_headers
parse_query
pre_get_posts
posts_selection
wp
template_redirect
get_header
wp_head
wp_enqueue_scripts
wp_print_styles
wp_print_scripts
```

I tried to define taxonomy in `registered_taxonomy`, but then my XAMPP wasn't loading page at all. I tried few tricks, but it doesn't work either.

And still, if I define it before `plugins_loaded` will it work? Because I register taxonomy inside plugin anyway...

Anyway, I need to have access to those taxonomies from plugin and dunno how to do it. I'd love to get some help ^^

EDIT 1: I explained why I get an error and what operation would fix it, but I don't know how to write it :) But as you wish, code with "error":

```
 function return_taxonomy_function() {
    $args = array(
        'hide_empty' => 0,
        'fields' => 'ids',
        'search'  => '',
    );
    $tax = new rav_search( array() );

    $tax->load_taxonomy('taxonomy', $args);
    $ret = $tax->taxonomy['taxonomy'];
    print_r($ret);
    return $ret;
 }

 add_action( 'init', 'return_taxonomy_function', 50 );

 add_action( 'return_taxonomy', 'return_taxonomy_function', 50 );

 print_r(do_action('return_taxonomy'));

 print_r(return_taxonomy_function())
```

After function I run few tests and only one works is `init`, but I can't get any value to my code from this (because it is called much later than my code). `$tax->load_taxonomy('miasto', $args);` is kinda allias to `get_terms()`.

What I need to do is simple `$value = return_taxonomy_function();` working, without error.

Comment: "After that I trying to call it from function and code". where? when? add the code that gives you invalid taxonomy error. there is no valid reason why it needs to be registered earlier, the error is within the code you are trying to access it from.

Comment: Done, still looking for help.

Comment: why does your code have to run before init when the taxonomy is registered?

Comment: Because plugin uses taxonomy names and values. So I need to get values from `get_term` into my plugin.

Comment: yes, but why do you need to get them before init?

Comment: Ofc I could do it everything with hooks. But it would be hell more complicated :/ And I have already wrote rest of code without hooks.

Comment: Why? `$value = return_taxonomy_function();` and many many functions using that value in many ways after. How am I supposed do it with or without hooks?

Comment: without hooks? you're not supposed to do it without hooks. *all* plugin code should be hooked to run at the appropriate time.

Comment: Okay, I explain: I write plugin which uses twig. First I need to declare taxonomy. Second I need to declare functions which uses taxonomy items. Third - I need to compile twig template using values from functions. `Init` don't work here, because I cant pass `init` value to Twig ...

Comment: And taxonomy thing is just another plugin, I wrote whole twig thing before in another plugin. So I cant just put everything under one function and hook it.

Comment: Wait.. would it work if I'd hook only Twig thing at very end of execution line?

Comment: Because I use those functions inside Twig anyway...